# Is there a way to define multiline XML in code in C# without having to change " to ""?

Tags: c#, xml, multiline

I would like to be able to **paste** chunks of XML into my C# code.

However, the best I can do is the **following**, but then I have to **search** and **replace** " with "".

**Is there a way to define multiline XML in C# code without having to alter the XML text like this?**

```
        public static string GetXml1()
        {
            return @"
<Customer>
  <FirstName status=""required"">Jim</FirstName>
  <LastName status=""required"">Smith</LastName>
</Customer>
";
        }
```

Comment: I assume there's a good reason that you don't use Linq to return small snippets of XML in a typesafe fashion?

Comment: you could also to replace `"` with `'` =)

Comment: I have XML that is already generated and need to copy it into a tool to test finding diffs between it, just thought there would be a simple way to do this, if I'm not mistaken in VB.NET you are able to just define a variable to a big block of XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the XML as a string resource then retrieve the XML as using `ResourceManager`.

Comment: What if we need to parse dynamic values inside xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily what you are askin for, but Box/Column Select might help if the lines are alligned. Just hold down the 'Alt'-key while you use the mouse to select the " you want to remove and press delete.